# Listing express.js requests

Tags: node.js, express, web-applications

Imagine the scenario in which a express.js app crashes.

Is it possible to log all the running requests before the server actually crashes?

For ex. "when the server crashes it was serving /apples and /lemons ..."

Comment: whats the error that crashes your server?

Comment: Nothing in particular. In case there is a fatal error I would like to log some information before the server crashes in order to have all the information for the bug fixing.

process.on('uncaughtException', function (err) {
  // log the error
  // log which where the running requests

  process.exit(1);
});

Comment: ... if you use a new version of node i would go for async/await. and "express-promise-router" and then use the error handling of express. This results for me in less callbacks, `.then`s and forgoten catched errors. (as express catches all) .. maybe this is a solution?...

Comment: Thanks, but to be honest it sounds too expensive: it means changing a lot on my app. I was looking for something like app.listRequest()

Comment: Put nginx in front, if you have an incoming request in the log but no response, you have what you wanted :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a logger like morgan or winston (morgan is specialized on express so it'll probably suits your needs)

It looks like you just need to requrie it and then use it in express, then it'll log every http request made.

https://github.com/expressjs/morgan

Comment: Don't they log after the request is served? If so, if the server crashes, the access request is not logged...

Comment: https://github.com/expressjs/morgan#immediate

You can give him an options object with the "immediate" property